# Mount SMB Share as File

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, modules

I am trying to use `g_mass_storage` to present files from a network as usb with my raspberry pi zero w.

Sadly, `g_mass_storage` takes a file for the `file` parameter.

I also tried creating a file with `dd` and giving it a fat32 file system with `mkdosfs` on the share, but that is pretty inefficient, as it has to load the entire file, before presenting it to usb. Which takes a while with my 1GB File, and I want to go into > 100 GB in the end.

That said, is there any way I can make a networkshare, that I could mount with `mount.cifs`, appear as if it were a file, or is there any other way I could achieve my goal ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bit baffled as to mounting 100Gb file if using the USB as a link (very big SD card?). Why not set up the USB as network and a SAMBA/Netatalk share to the card?

Comment: This should be attached to a Wii. Sadly the Wii does not support loading shares over Network afaik. So with my solution, I want to stream the files from a networkshare to the Wii. The Files should at no point be on the sd card of the Pi Zero W, but straight from the network through the Cpu to the USB to the Wii.

Comment: Did you ever get further with this? It seems you and I had the exact same idea to use `g_mass_storage` to allow the Wii to load games from the network.